# Implications of switching RSA padding schemes

Tags: rsa, side-channel-attack, pkcs1, rsa-pss

In my company we want to switch from PKCSv1.5 to PSS for RSA signing. This is because of the [marvin attack vector](https://people.redhat.com/%7Ehkario/marvin/).

My question is, if an adversary can see many similar messages that were signed with both schemes, does this have an adverse effect on security?

If so, are there known fixes that won't force a padding switch (i.e. adding random sleeps to server replies to counter timing attack?)?

Comment: Note that RSA **encryption** can also be used for authentication, but RSA_ ciphersuites that use RSA encryption that way are hardly used anymore; most organizations use sign-only certificates and will disable those cipher suites, relying on ones that have signatures for authentication and of course forward security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the next section for why it's likely not necessary to make any change. But let's answer the question anyway.

> If an adversary can see many similar messages that were signed with both ([RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A90%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C721%2Cnull%5D) aka PKCSv1.5 and [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A78%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C314%2Cnull%5D) aka PSS), does this have an adverse effect on security?

**No**.

That extends to messages that an adversary chooses entirely. For RSASSA-PSS *alone*, we have a proof that if this was possible, then the RSA conjecture would be false. For RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (with correct verification) *alone*, we have empirical evidence to that effect: this has been studied intensively for >40 years with no progress.

For signature of the same message under *both* schemes (as asked), that holds if different public/private key pairs and certificates are used, which is recommendable (if only because it's poor practice to obtain two certificates for the same key pair and certificates usable for signature specify which signature scheme is used, or should at least for RSASSA-PSS).

Even with key pair shared between the two schemes (as considered till the end of this section), we have a good security argument (but not a security reduction) if a different hash is used in the two schemes, e.g. RSASSA-PSS uses SHA-512 or SHA3-256, and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 uses SHA-256 or SHA-1<sup>*</sup>.

If the same hash is used for both schemes, this is still secure, but arguments that can be made of that are weaker.

If hashing a long message twice is a performance issue, we can hash the message with the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 hash assumed collision-resistant (e.g. SHA-256), use that to build the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature which will remain compatible with existing verification code for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (with e.g. SHA-256), and sign the hash (which becomes a so-called pre-hash) with RSASSA-PSS (e.g. with SHA3-256 for peace of mind).

---

You want to replace [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A66%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C652%2Cnull%5D) with [RSAES-OAEP](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A44%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C640%2Cnull%5D) or [RSA-KEM](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5990) in *encryption* applications, but don't hurry to replace RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 with RSASSA-PSS in *signature* applications. The only security benefit is theoretical, and there are practical issues.

Contrary to what the question's [linked article](https://people.redhat.com/%7Ehkario/marvin/) sneakily suggests in introduction, it's not to fear that in signature-only applications, Bleichenbacher's attacks or variations allow an attacker to sign in a way such that a correct implementation of signature verification accepts the signature.

Issues that can actually happen (and thus did, recurrently for the first):

- Adversary can sign or decipher (per any RSA variant) by exploiting a side channel on RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 *decryption* code. While countermeasures in that code are possible, they tend to be brittle, and the appropriate solution is to drop RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 encryption and decryption in favor of RSAES-OAEP or (for key establishment) RSA-KEM.
- Adversary can sign by exploiting an error in the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature verification code. This attack is purely mathematical, it requires no side-channel. The appropriate countermeasure is to use correct RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature verification code.

Drawbacks of RSASSA-PSS compared to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5:

- Signing the same message twice with the same key will result in two different signatures. This makes Known Answer Tests impossible in unit tests of code that signs.
- An intentionally rigged implementation of RSASSA-PSS can exfiltrate information using that randomness (such as the private key), and that's not externally detectable by verifying that the signature is conforming.
- Signing requires a RNG. That can very practically go wrong (e.g. hang for entropy). Good luck for convincing a randomly selected security auditor that the math of RSASSA-PSS is such that really, it's not much of a problem if the RNG is broken, as long as it's not broken in the above way that is.
- Specifying RSASSA-PSS and the hash is not enough for interoperability. You formally need to specify e.g. "RSASSA-PSS with SHA-256 and MFG1 using SHA-256, and salt such that…", and in implementations it's possible to accidentally use RSASSA-PSS with SHA-256 and MFG1 using SHA-1. That's secure even though SHA-1 is not, but not interoperable.
- Correspondingly, the interface to specify RSASSA-PSS parameters is sometime more complex than the one to specify the single RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 parameter: the hash function. In Oracle's Java, that required the new class [`PSSParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/PSSParameterSpec.html).
- Certificates for an RSA public key usable for RSASSA-PSS and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 are not interoperable. That, or/and people or implementations confuse or conflate the algorithm the key is intended to sign with, and the algorithm the key is certified with.

This is not to say that RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is safe from side channels, nor as safe as RSASSA-PSS from this standpoint. However, the possible side channel attacks are unrelated to Bleichenbacher's attacks or the linked article.

> Are there known fixes that won't force a padding switch (i.e. adding random sleeps to server replies to counter timing attack?)?

No side channel is to fear in signature verification, since no secret is involved. Side channels are possible in signature generation, but none remotely similar to that in the linked attack, and all those I know apply to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSASSA-PSS alike.

It's notoriously difficult to fully repair RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 decryption from side-channel attacks (e.g. BouncyCastle made several attempts that all reached the "it's now secure" point). Random sleeps are hard to get right, and even then don't work reliably for adversaries able to run code on the same CPU (e.g. other process, JavaScript/WebAsm in a browser, virtual machine).

---

<sup>*</sup> SHA-1 must not be used in new application, because it's broken from the standpoint of collisions and chosen-prefix-collision. However it remains secure in some applications, including HMAC-SHA-1; and in signature if the signer sets some field of the first 64 bytes of the message with data unpredictable by adversaries.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Even though the specific attack won't work, you implied that there are other side-channel attacks. Currently the system is set up so an adversary can send any messages it wants as many times as it want. We are probably vulnerable to some other timing attack? We are using 2048 bits keys... maybe this isn't sufficient under such conditions?

Comment: If in "an adversary can send any messages it wants as many times as it want" the thing that the adversary sends messages to _verifies_ signatures in what the adversary sends, then it can't be vulnerable to any side-channel attack (as opposed to fault attack, mathematical attack, exploitation of faulty code like buffer overflow or partial signature verification): there is no secret involved that could leak. If that thing signs what the adversary supplies, well, the countermeasures to that are essentially common to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and RSASSA-PSS. And that's drifting from the question.

Comment: @whomaniac To reiterate what fgrieu wrote: switching from PKCS1v1.5 signature to PSS does not reduce the risk of side channel vulnerabilities. I'd even add that PSS is arguably more at risk of implementation defects (specifically buffer overflows with small keys) due to its increased complexity, although good functional testing should find any such defect.

Comment: With respect to PKCS#1v1.5 decryption, a tricky aspect is that even if the implementation of decryption itself is perfectly free of side channel vulnerabilities, _consuming_ the decrypted plaintext can itself introduce a side channel. For example, TLS ≤1.2 with an RSA-encryption cipher suite requires doing just a little bit of parsing on the result of decryption, and that's enough to be a potentially exploitable remote timing side channel if not done in constant time.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': do you mean that after RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 decryption (version might matter) did it's thing in a Bleichenbacher-safe way including verifying the specified padding and giving it an OK, further tests of the deciphered plaintext can allow attack usable to decipher (or sign with the same private key)? If so, I don't know that one, any pointer?

Comment: @fgrieu Apparently the original publication was [Kilma, Pokorný and Rosa 2003](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/052.pdf). Here's the [resulting OpenSSL patch](https://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=104811162730834&w=2), and the [WolfSSL patch](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/pull/1229/commits/fd455d5a5e9fef24c208e7ac7d3a4bc58834cbf1) was as recent as [ROBOT](https://robotattack.org/). I'm not sure about the practicality of a remote attack when the only leakage is timing and not an alert, but remote timing attacks are almost always more practical than most people claim.

Comment: Intuitively speaking, the Bleichenbacher oracle is possible because an attacker can tell whether the byte at a certain position has a certain value. The padding in PKCS#1v1.5 causes the server to go through a valid-or-invalid branch depending on the value of bytes at certain positions. The version number at the beginning of the TLS ≤1.2 ciphertext is the value of bytes at the next positions. From my understanding of the attack, it doesn't become significantly more expensive when the bytes are at larger positions.